# JList custom selection behaviour - to include everything from the item clicked to the end of the list

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I'm using a **JList** to record & display changes to my data.  I'm interested in being able to "undo" those changes.  For that reason I would like to ensure that, whatever the user clicks on the list, the selection includes everything from that item to the end of the list.  I had thought that

```
    lstLog.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
            if(!lse.getValueIsAdjusting())
                if((lse.getFirstIndex() == (lstLog.getModel().getSize() - 1)) || (lse.getLastIndex() == (lstLog.getModel().getSize() - 1))) {
//                  this.valueChanged(lse);
                }
                else {
                    int lowestSelection; 
                    if(lse.getFirstIndex() < 0) lowestSelection = lse.getLastIndex();
                    else if (lse.getLastIndex() < 0) lowestSelection = lse.getFirstIndex();
                    else lowestSelection = ((lse.getFirstIndex() < lse.getLastIndex()) ? lse.getLastIndex() : lse.getFirstIndex());
                    lstLog.setSelectionInterval(lowestSelection, lstLog.getModel().getSize() - 1);
                }
        }
    });
```

would do it, but it's practically ignored.  Tutorials on writing **ListSelectionListeners** from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html), [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoJListEventswithaListSelectionListener.htm) and [Riga U](http://www.cs.rtu.lv/PharePub/Java/Tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) all use exactly the same (unhelpful) example.  Does anyone have a better way?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try wrapping your call to `setSelectionInterval()` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: @Catalina Be careful here - a call to setSelectionInterval() will invoke the valueChanged callback, so you end up with an infinite loop. Probably better to write your own ListSelectionModel.

Comment: @FredK true, but my statement starting `if((lse.getFirstIndex() == (lstLog.getModel().getSize() - 1)` should stop the recursion.  I'll try it.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland using invokeLater() seems to make it work every second time, or just after I've clicked the last item.

Comment: read methods in ListSelectionModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works brilliantly!  Thanks, @mKorbel !

```
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

/**
*
* @author MaskedCoder
*/
public class ActionListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel implements ListSelectionModel {
    ListModel thisModel;

    public ActionListSelectionModel(JList iniList) {
        super();
        thisModel = iniList.getModel();
        super.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        super.setAnchorSelectionIndex(thisModel.getSize() - 1);
        // maybe add datalistener to update AnchorSelection when items added/removed
    }

    private int betterOf(int index0, int index1) {
        if(index0 < 0) return index1;
        else if (index1 < 0) return index0;
        else return ((index0 < index1) ? index1 : index0);
    }

    /*
    * ListSelectionModel implementation
    */
    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        super.setSelectionInterval(thisModel.getSize() - 1, betterOf(index0, index1));
    }

    @Override
    public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        // don't want to add, so just do same as above
        super.setSelectionInterval(thisModel.getSize() - 1, betterOf(index0, index1));
    }

    @Override
    public void setAnchorSelectionIndex(int anchorIndex) {
        super.setAnchorSelectionIndex(thisModel.getSize() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertIndexInterval(int index, int length, boolean before) {
        super.setSelectionInterval(thisModel.getSize() - 1, index);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeIndexInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        // do nothing.  Only (1) interval and it will never be removed.
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionMode(int selectionMode) {
        super.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    }

}
```